# How to get 30 days from last date - Laravel & Sql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The last date some  clients visited was `1st August`, i am trying to get all clients who haven't visited for the past `30 days` from the last visit.

Below is how i try to achieve but i still get empty response. What am i not doing right please?

```
 $client = Client::whereRaw('ADDDATE(last_seen) = ? ', 'INTERVAL 30 DAY');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `Carbon` then you can use `subDays` method  to get users who didn't visited last 30 days

```
$client = Client::where('status_id', 'active')
   ->where( 'last_seen', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(30))
   ->get();
```